# How to launch an instance of my Flask app on Heroku

Tags: flask, heroku

I am having a hard time deploying my little flask app to Heroku. I created it in visual studio community and just want to deploy it now to Heroku.

App code:

https://github.com/Phasor/QR-Site-2020

I signed up for a free account at Heroku and am following this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#deploy-the-app

I ran the following commands in their CLI:

```
git clone https://github.com/heroku/QR-Site-2020.git
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

When I write `heroku ps:scale web=1` I get the following error:
`Couldn't find that process type (web).`

Looking for advice online it seems I need to define something called a `Procfile`. I have tried to do that and defined it as:
`web: gunicorn runserver:app` although I am very unsure that is correct (I normally just hit the "play" button in VS to run the app locally). Adding the Procfile does not solve the error message. I believe it should not hav the .txt extension but not sure you can create a text file without that in VS.

Originally I was not using `gunicorn` but think I may need to use that for Heroku so I added that to my requirements.txt.

Can anyone give me any pointers?  Thanks

Comment: Here is an example of deploying a Flask app on Heroku: https://github.com/NNTin/twitter-backend I looked at your GitHub and see a couple of mistakes. Your file is not named `Procfile` it is named `Procfile.txt`. It needs to be at the root directory. You are not supposed to commit the `env/` folder, and project relevant files (`*.sln` and `*.pyproj`). The content of your `Procfile` is the CLI command you write when you are in the root directory. In my linked example it would be `python app.py` or `gunicorn app:app`. You just prefix it with a `web: `

Comment: Thanks. I am linking my github to visual studio which is adding all these other VS files files. I guess I need to exclude them.